# Efficient bit remapping algorithm

Tags: c#, random, mapping, bit-manipulation, shuffle

I have a use case where I need to scramble an input in such a way that:

1. Each specific input always maps to a specific pseudo-random output.
2. The output must shuffle the input sufficiently so that an incrementing input maps to a pseudo-random output.

For example, if the input is 64 bits, there must be exactly 2^64 unique outputs, and these must break incrementing inputs as much as possible (arbitrary requirement).

I will code this in C#, but can translate from Java or C, so long as there are not SIMD intrinsics. What I am looking for is some already existing code, rather than reinventing the wheel.

I have looked on Google, but haven't found anything that does a 1:1 mapping.

Comment: "As much as possible", would that mean reversing the bits (increment gives changes that are as large as possible), or in the "most random" way (what would that even mean?)

Comment: Just reversing the bits isn't enough?

Comment: Reversing won't help as that is still patterned. I need them shuffled to some arbitrary degree.

Comment: Ok I have an idea, it'll take a minute to test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work fairly well:

```
const long multiplier = 6364136223846793005;
const long mulinv_multiplier = -4568919932995229531;
const long offset = 1442695040888963407;

static long Forward(long x)
{
    return x * multiplier + offset;
}

static long Reverse(long x)
{
    return (x - offset) * mulinv_multiplier;
}
```

You can change the constants to whatever as long as `multiplier` is odd and `mulinv_multiplier` is the modular multiplicative inverse (see [wiki:modular multiplicative inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) or Hackers Delight 10-15 Exact Division by Constants) of `multiplier` (modulo 2^64, obviously - and that's why `multiplier` has to be odd, otherwise it has no inverse).

The offset can be anything, but make it relatively prime with 2^64 just to be on the safe side.

These specific constants come from Knuths linear congruential generator.

There's one small thing: it puts the complement of the LSB of the input in the LSB of the result. If that's a problem, you could just rotate it by any nonzero amount.

---

For 32 bits, the constants can be `multiplier = 0x4c957f2d`, `offset = 0xf767814f`, `mulinv_multiplier = 0x329e28a5`.

For 64 bits, `multiplier = 12790229573962758597`, `mulinv_multiplier = 16500474117902441741` may work better.

---

Or, you could use a CRC, which is [reversible](http://www.danielvik.com/2010/10/calculating-reverse-crc.html) for this use (ie the input is the same size as the CRC) for CRC64 it requires some modifications of course.

Comment: I plotted the distribution of the most significant byte for the 32 bit permute. It's 0.901388 which translates to 12.877%. Of course that's not as good as pure random, which will be 0%, but not bad. However, the 64 bit is 42.5772%, which is not good.

Comment: I tried another idea I had, but have no mathematical proof if it's collision free, and that is to use good ol' CRC32. It produces a perfect distribution and doesn't collide on a 20e6 run. What are your thoughts?

Comment: @harold How much of the comment trail is edited back into the answer?  Could we do that and clean up the comment trail please?

Comment: @IanC How much of the comment trail is edited back into the question and/or answer?  Could we do that and clean up the comment trail please?

Answer (score 1):

Just from the top of my head:

1. Shift the input: Make sure you keep every bit, i.e. use two shift operations in different directions and OR the result together.
2. Apply an static XOR.

Everything else that comes to my mind won't be bijective. However, a search for bijective might bring up something useful ;D

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking. "bijective" that's the term I didn't know. Thanks.